# Cookies missing on a xhr request on response header

Tags: php, cookies, cross-domain

So I have this php code on **a.com/test.php**

```php7
<?php 
require_once 'wp-blog-header.php'; // get WordPress core

status_header(200); // WP way of saying the response it 200 (OK)

// allow CORS ; 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://b.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'); // allow credentials

print_r($_COOKIE); // show cookies

die(); // bye
```

And on site **b.com** , open devTools and paste in:

```javascript
fetch('http://a.com/test.php?cache='+Date.now(),{credentials: 'include'})).then(a=>a.text()).then(console.log) ; // make sure we're not getting a cached response.
```

My problem is that accessing **a.com/test.php** directly has cookies set (at least wp testcookie , but I am also logged in and there are a bunch more) but with the ajax call from **b.com** that is empty.
What am I missing, why can't the script on a.com see cookies on it's own domain?
I am not trying to get cookies back to **b.com** . Main goal is to find out on **b.com** if the user/browser is logged in on **a.com**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#differences_from_jquery: _“fetch() won’t send cross-origin cookies unless you set the credentials init option (to include).”_

Comment: My apologies if I was not clear. I don't want to sent cookies from one domain to the other. I am asking in the name of b.com if this user is logged in on a.com . The a.com/test.php can do whatever he wants with it's own cookies and tell me just that, if it is logged in or not based on what he knows

Comment: You want the cookies that are stored _for_ `a.com` in your browser, to be included in this request _to_ `a.com` - which fetch won’t do with cross-origin requests, unless you explicitly instruct it to do so.

Comment: no, not at all. I don't want to pass cookie. I only want the script on a.com, when it is called , to access it's own cookies, like it is when accessing a.com/test.php directly

Comment: … and for that to happen, your browser must _send_ the cookie with that request, and since you are using `fetch`, it will only do so when explicitly instructed to.

Comment: so I've updated the code to send cookies as well,tested and still nothing; but the way I see it it should not do anything , because I don't sent the cookies for a.com when I'm on b.com ( I should not have access to them); I am asking a.com what is it's relationship with current browser

Comment: _“And on site b.com , open devTools and paste in”_ - not sure if that is a proper way to test this, whether this provides all the necessary context. Have you tried this with code that actually “lives” inside your B.com page already?

Comment: _“because I don't sent the cookies for a.com when I'm on b.com ( I should not have access to them)”_ - no one said you should have _access_ to them, but that they should be send _with_ the request that is made to A.com. That, and _you_ “having access”, are still two completely different things.